# Dynamic express router structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am relatively new to routing with Express and pretty confused about how to accomplish this task.

I have an array of rankings with about 100 teams in it. I want each team to have a page associated with it, so for example `localhost:1234/gonzaga` would show stats for 'gonzaga'.

I understand using `app.get('/:teamName')` but I don't know how I would make the page unique for each team.

Edit: got it working using templates and the answer given, sorry for the confusion as I am very new to this.

Should I populate the data on the page from the frontend? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We don't know how you render your routes or if you are using a rest api

Comment: "Should I populate the data on the page from the frontend?" — The *whole point* of `app.get('/:teamName')` is that you have the identifying value on the backend so you can populate it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create unique pages for each team using Express, you can use dynamic routing and templates. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to accomplish this task:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 1234; // or any other port you prefer

const ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get('/:teamName', (req, res) => {
  const teamName = req.params.teamName;
  res.render('teamTemplate', { team });
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Now, when you access a URL like localhost:1234/gonzaga, Express will capture the :teamName parameter and render the corresponding team's data using the template

Comment: We don't know if op is using templates

Comment: @Konrad - The point of this answer is to illustrate HOW to use templates to solve the problem they've described.